# Converting Index Match Formula with Dynamic Range to VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, indexing, match

My Original formula is as follows:

```
=INDEX(MIR!$A:$A,MATCH(1,(MIR!$H:$H=TRI!$W2)*(MIR!$I:$I=TRI!$L2),0))
```

I created the following VBA Code for this and while the code does add the formula to the appropriate range, the formula does NOT work. It's as if the Array portion is not being applied.  I've looked everywhere to figure this out but I obviously am not looking in the right spot. Please advise.

```
Range("B2").Select
Selection.FormulaArray = _
    "=INDEX(MIR!C1,MATCH(1,(MIR!C8=TRI!RC23)*(MIR!C9=TRI!RC12),0))"
Range("B2", "B" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).FillDown
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using xlR1C1 notation but VBA is reading it as xlA1 notation. `MIR!C1` is not `MIR!A:A`, it is first row, third column on the MIR worksheet (e.g. `MIR!C1`). The formula is put on the worksheet as,

```
=INDEX(MIR!C1,MATCH(1,(MIR!C8=TRI!RC23)*(MIR!C9=TRI!RC12),0))
```

Use a formula in xlA1 notation.

```
Range("B2").FormulaArray = "=INDEX(MIR!$A:$A,MATCH(1,(MIR!$H:$H=TRI!$W2)*(MIR!$I:$I=TRI!$L2),0))"
```

Btw, you should really cut those full column references in the MATCH down to the used data range.